# Is Nested GroupBy supported in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, group-by

I have a categories table with the fields "id", "category_id", "name" where "category_id" is the id of the parent category. My requirement is that I need to group the categories like below.

```
Europe
 - England
Asia
 - India
   - Kerala
     - Kochi
```

Note - Here Europe,England,Asia,India,Kerala,Kochi are categories. Asia is the parent category of India and India is the parent category of Kerala and Kerala is the parent category of Kochi.

Is there some nested groupBy solution?

Comment: group by on what? it's unclear what you want to achieve

Comment: do you wanna somehow render this in blade recursively

Comment: Yes, I want to display the categories hierarchically in the blade file.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that it's a one-to-many self-referencing relationship i.e. one category can only belong to some other category (single parent)

And your `Category` model should look something like this:

```
public function parent() {
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}

public function children() {
   return $this->hasMany('App\Category');
}
```

In  your `main` blade template, you have:

```
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
       @foreach ($menu_items as $item)
             @include('menu', $item)
       @endforeach
  </ul>
```

Where `$menu_items` is the list of all parent categories ( categories where category_id is null or 0 )

And your `menu` blade template:

```
@if ( $item->children->isNotEmpty() )
<li class="nav-item {{ $item->parents->isNotEmpty() ? 'dropdown-submenu' : 'dropdown' }}">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="{{ $item->slug ? url($item->slug) : 'javascript:void(0);' }}" id="navbarDropdown{{ $item->id }}" role="button" data-toggle="hover">
        {{ $item->title }}
    </a>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown{{ $item->id }}">
        @foreach ($item->children as $item)

            @include('menu', $item)

        @endforeach
    </ul>
@else
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ $item->slug ? url($item->slug) : 'javascript:void(0);' }}">{{ $item->title }}</a>
@endif
</li>
```

I literally pasted this code from a project I worked on recently to give you an idea about nested drop-down, you've to work on the styling part yourself. But this code is enough to give you a proper understanding.

PS: this all untested. let me know if something doesn't work